# Kafka Connect: Two Sink and Two Source connectors read/write to the same topic, cause a cyclic issue?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have an onprem (different location) and atlas mongo db and we want bidirectional data sync between these databases. It seems to work, but we are trying to anticipate any infinity loop situations.

In the current POC, we have

- (Atlas) Connect Worker that has a Atlas Source and Sink Connector
- (Mongo onprem) Connect worker that has Mongo Source and Sink Connector
- Writing to the same, let's call it Mongo-Sync topic.

Will this cause a cyclic issue when for e.g. atlas adds data and its sent to kafka topic and then the sink on the same side tries to process it causing an issue?

Is a better solution to use two topics, where each topic handles one side of the data flow?

Comment: Can't `mongod` do replication on its own? But yeah, if you do some operation, then read the oplog, then send that elsewhere to a new database, and then read its oplog, and send it back, you've created a loop. Try to implement CQRS; use a different collection for writes and reads.

Comment: Thanks, I ll check the oplog. We can't use different collections for reads and writes since they both need to look the same and interchangeable data sources.

Comment: I believe the connector itself is reading the oplog; that's what I'm saying - I believe it'll create a loop